# Change color of all instances of a Word(s) in RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net, colors, richtextbox, highlight

Im trying to make it so, I can Specify a word or words in the code, and When I compile/debug I want the Program to search a richtextbox for all instances of those words and change there color.

```
Dim GRAB as String = New WebClient().DownloadString("example.com")
RichTextBox1.Text = GRAB
` Color Word Code Here
```

Ive looked up alot of things on google, but Everything I've tried will only highlight the FIRST word.

Sorry if my typing is bad, im typing with a broken arm..

Can someone help me with this, or write a quick snippet?

Comment: You might be interested in this [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10675/Enabling-syntax-highlighting-in-a-RichTextBox)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Dim wordslist As New List(Of String)
wordslist.Add("Hello")
wordslist.Add("World")

Dim len As Integer = RichTextBox1.TextLength

For Each word As String In wordslist

    Dim lastindex = RichTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(word)
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    While index < lastindex

    RichTextBox1.Find(word, index, len, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
    index = RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, index) + 1

    End While

Next
```

Modified and translated from C# from [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8683fec1-f269-45a3-9dd7-6e73e6be464f/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the text which will have a colour change.

```
RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("example"),4)
 RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Would render the ".com" in red
or

```
RichTextBox1.Select(6,4)
  RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
```

Would do the same

Comment: Whoops, I need to slow down and read the whole question! Answer only holds up if the string GRAB is "example.com".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose u want to make 'Dim' to Blue color as VS:-

Paste this:

```
If RichTextBox1.Text.EndsWith("Dim") Then
        RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.TextLength - 3, 3)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
        RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBox1.TextLength)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black
    End If
```

Add this code to RichTextBox to Text_Changed.